# What were emergency procedures for failure of launch vehicles with nuclear upper stages?

Tags: abort, ntr, risk-management

There were many studies in the 1960s, and a lesser number of later ones, for launch vehicles with nuclear-thermal upper stages. I have rarely seen mention of what emergency procedures were considered for launch failures.

[Dangers of launching a nuclear thermal rocket](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4560/dangers-of-launching-a-nuclear-thermal-rocket)  suggests the hazard is not extreme - for the case of an NTR started in orbit. A nuclear upper stage has the possibility of running for some time but failing to reach orbit.

Even in the pre-Chernobyl era, there has to have been serious consideration of this. What studies were done, and is there any available summary of the results?

Comment: You may want to include studies of space-based reactors, which were more numerous (and were actually deployed!), into the consideration. Basically, robust reactor shielding and de-spinning (maintaining positive attitude control) are your best friends.

Comment: Remember that a nuclear-thermal engine doesn't have a huge mass of stuff just looking to go boom. While it certainly could crash it's not going to go up in an approximation of a tactical nuke. Furthermore, the real danger is used rods, not fresh ones.

Comment: Nukes, schmukes. Real rocketeers use [liquid fluoride](http://www.astronautix.com/engines/g1.htm) and hydrazine.

Comment: A bit about "poison wires" to prevent criticality from water getting inside the pressure vessel: 
http://www.sciencemadness.org/lanl1_a/lib-www/la-pubs/00397413.pdf

Comment: There is some concern about an unused NTR core falling into a lake or ocean, which serves as a moderator and causes criticality (more a "meltdown, release of radionucleides" problem than a nuclear explosion.)

Answer (score 4):

50 years old abort routines are hard to come by, but the [NERVA-specs](http://fas.org/nuke/space/nerva-spec.pdf) (unclassified 9/8/1970) clearly specify a malfunction mode in which the engine should be able to provide a minimum of thrust and impulse. The values stated (thrust of 30000 pounds, impulse of 10⁸ lb-seconds) are enough to direct the upper stage away from densely populated areas, towards a landing in the ocean. The engine should also be capable of operating with just one turbo pump
Normal procedure for saving the crew during a launch failure is separating the capsule from from the rocket, and fire a solid rocket escape tower to get away, followed by a normal descent with parachutes. The Mercury capsules, pre-dating the NERVA program, was equipped with escape towers.